# How to send javascript created .png in email for outlook client?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, email, outlook

The existing workflow has an html template which gets populated with data and sent as an automated email.

Change done, I have to embed a line chart created from an XML in the email and send it to intended recipients. I have used jscharts.js for creating line charts and these charts are successfully embedded in template. When I send the email through an automated process then this chart is not getting displayed on the email client.

Is there any way using which I can capture it and send it across through email?

PS: scripts are written in python and js only.

Comment: I put together a python class for such uses. http://datamakessense.com/easy-scheduled-emailing-with-python-for-typical-bi-needs/

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible to reliably embed javascript into an email. Your best bet is to create an HTML email, and render the graph to a raster file format (PNG for instance) in 1 or 2 ways:

1. If you can utilize Google Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/), that'd be easiest. (This might not be possible due to company policies, or too much data, etc)
2. Render your own graphs server side and deliver them as images. Properly done, you could render the image exactly once and cache it. If this is a daily email, perhaps it'd be as simple as embedding the image tag as `<img src="http://yourserver.com/graphs/<user_id>_YYYYMMDD.png" />` -- which of course means you'd be free to use whatever graphing library is out there...